# Inequality proof in $\mathbb{R}$, $\dfrac{a}{2(a+b)\sqrt{b}}<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{b}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

I'm starting to study math, so far I know the axioms of $\mathbb{R}$ and some basic properties.
Let $a,b >0$ then $$\frac{a}{2(a+b)\sqrt{b}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}}$$

I tried to assume that it is valid under the hypotheses and then do the reverse way to prove it but I can't come up with anything concrete. Thanks!

Comment: Start with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt b}{\sqrt b \sqrt{a+b}}$, then use the usual “trick” to multiply numerator and denominator with $\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt b$.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be proven in many ways, BUT I somehow managed to pull a beautiful AM-GM inequality here lol

AM of (a+b) and b > GM of (a+b) and b
$$\frac{(a+b)+b}{2}>\sqrt{(a+b)×b}$$
or $$\frac{a}{2}>\sqrt{(a+b)×b} - b$$
or $$a- \frac{a}{2}>\sqrt{(a+b)×b} - b$$
or $$- \frac{a}{2}>\sqrt{(a+b)×b} - b - a$$
So after reversing the sign,
$$\frac{a}{2}< (a+b) - \sqrt{(a+b)×b}$$
Dividing both sides by (a+b)$\sqrt{b}$
$$\frac{a}{2(a+b)\sqrt{b}}< \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}}$$

Hence proved.

If you wanna know what's AM,  it's arithmetic mean, and GM is geometric mean. AM of x and y is (x+y)/2 and GM of x and y is √(xy). AM>GM always (it can be proven easily)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about AM and GM, I'm going to try to try it so I can use it as a tool for other demonstrations.

Comment: No problem. They are very handy in cases of inequalities. You should see the proof of AM > GM. It uses direct subtraction to check if the result is positive or negative, which in itself is a useful method of proving inequalities

Answer (score 0):

As you said, we \try to do in reverse way. For simple inequalities, our task should be try to reduce it into a 'nice' form, (get rid of fraction, square roots), so to get some 'always true' stuff.
\begin{align*}\dfrac{a}{2(a+b)\sqrt{b}}<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{b}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}}&\iff \dfrac{a}{2(a+b)\sqrt{b}}<\dfrac{\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{b}\sqrt{a+b}}\\
&\iff a<2\sqrt{a+b}(\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{b})\\
&\iff a+2b>2\sqrt{b(a+b)} \\&\iff a^2+4ab+4b^2>4ab+4b^2\\&\iff a^2>0\end{align*}
**Edit:** Thanks for clarification. But now we have $a>0$, so using backward $\impliedby$ can still prove the inequality as required.

Comment: Ohh, i understand. Yes, the last inecuality is true because its a sum of positive terms. Something that was not clear to me is this step $\dfrac{a+b}{\sqrt{a+b}}=\sqrt{a+b}$, you used that $\frac{a^m}{a^n}=a^{m-n}$, I thought it only worked for integers exponents, can I use it if the exponents are real too? By the way, thanks for the response, it was very helpful.

Comment: These are index laws, which holds for any $a>0$ and $m,n\in\mathbb{R}$. At least if $m,n$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, they are easy to prove.

Comment: Great, thanks, I'll try them!

Comment: There's a mistake between lines 2 and 3. Fixing it shows this method doesn't work.

$a < 2\sqrt{a+b}(\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{b})$

$\iff a < 2(a+b) - 2\sqrt{a+b}\sqrt{b}$

$\iff a < 2a+2b - 2\sqrt{a+b}\sqrt{b}$

$\iff  0 < a + 2b - 2\sqrt{a+b}\sqrt{b}$

$\iff a + 2b > 2\sqrt{a+b}\sqrt{b}$

$\iff a + 2b > \sqrt{4(a+b)(b)}$ 

$\iff a + 2b > \sqrt{4ab + 4b^2}$

$\iff (a+2b)^2 > 4ab + 4b^2$

$\iff a^2 + 4ab + 4b^2 > 4ab + 4b^2$

$\iff a^2 > 0$

Comment: Edit: Apologies for the careless rejection. As you pointed out, the method does work.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, it was very clear.

Answer (score 0):

To show
$\dfrac{a}{2(a+b)\sqrt{b}}<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{b}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}}$,
since $a, b > 0$
can write
$a=u^2, b=v^2$
with $u, v > 0$.

This becomes
$\dfrac{u^2}{2(u^2+v^2)\sqrt{v^2}}
<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{v^2}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\\$

or
$\dfrac{u^2}{2(u^2+v^2)v}
<\dfrac{1}{v}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\\$

or,
multiplying by
$v(u^2+v^2)$,
$\dfrac{u^2}{2}
<(u^2+v^2)-v\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\\$

or
$v\sqrt{u^2+v^2}
\lt \dfrac{u^2}{2}+v^2$.

Squaring,
this is
$v^2(u^2+v^2)
\lt \dfrac{u^4}{4}+u^2v^2+v^4$
or,
since $u^2v^2+v^4$
cancel out,
$0 < \dfrac{u^4}{4}
$
which is true.

Now just reverse all the steps.

Comment: Thanks! All the forms they provided helped me so I know some tricks for other demonstrations.